# Mouseup event not firing with code inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseup

I'm trying to create Press & Hold confirmation button with jQuery. The problem is that `mouseup` event is not firing when I insert code within this function. It only fires when the function is empty and there is only `console.log`. Here is example:

```
self.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.addClass('-loading -progress');
    clickDuration = setTimeout(function(e) {
        self.trigger('click').removeClass('-progress');
        console.log('clicked for 2 seconds');
    }, parseInt(confirmDuration));
    console.log(e);
}).on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    self.removeClass('-loading -progress');
    clearTimeout(clickDuration);
    console.log(e);
});
```

`mouseup` won't fire.

```
self.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
}).on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

`mouseup` will fire.

Anyway I have created full example of my code and you can play with it live here: https://jsbin.com/bozusiboku/1/edit?js,output

Thanks!

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes No that's not where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works if you remove the class `-loading` from your statement `self.addClass('-loading -progress');`.

`-loading` adds the CSS `pointer-events: none`, which disables mouse events on your button and keeps mouseup from firing.

See: [MDN: Pointer Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).